# How to set a default value based on user's previous value

Tags: javascript, default-value

I want to have a default value based on what the user put before. For example, if in an input I put '5' I want to see that the value of that input is 5 when I refresh the page, but if I put 6 I want the default value to be 6. Thanks (i'm a begginer)

Comment: You should save it and restore it from somewhere. I suggest you have a look at localstorage

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Do you know how events work in javascript?

Comment: I don't know why folks marked you down.  You asked a fair question - and got a useful (for you, and for others!) reply.  Thank you for "accepting" one of your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
localStorage = window.localStorage;
localStorage.setItem('inputDefault', '5');

let inputDefault = localStorage.getItem('inputDefault');
```

Here's a more practical example I quickly whipped up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Local Storage Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setLocalStorageValue()
        {
            let myNumberInputField = document.getElementById('myNumberInput');
            let myNewValue = myNumberInputField.value;

            let localStorage = window.localStorage;
            localStorage.setItem('defaultValue', myNewValue);
        }

        function getLocalStoredValue()
        {
            let localStorage = window.localStorage;
            let defaultValue = localStorage.getItem('defaultValue');

            let myNumberInputField = document.getElementById('myNumberInput');
            myNumberInputField.value = defaultValue;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getLocalStoredValue()">
<label>My Number Input
    <input type="number" id="myNumberInput" value="0" onchange="setLocalStorageValue()">
</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Does this answer your question? Note how I am writing back to local storage on the onchange event of the input in question, and I read from local storage when the body of the html loads.