# How can I store input values even after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm on a JavaScript LAB mission where we should take user input and use it as dimensions for a canvas.

My problem is that we are given HTML to stick with (can't be modified) which contains a submit button that reloads the page after the user submits its dimensions.

My question is how can I store the input value even after reloading the page?

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

  <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
  <form id="sizePicker">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
  <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

  <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
  <table id="pixelCanvas">
  </table>

  <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can try `localStorage` here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a default value based on user's previous value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823818/how-to-set-a-default-value-based-on-users-previous-value)

Comment: Typically, you submit an html `<form>` to some "action", so the value is sent to the server ... and the *server* is responsible for "remembering" ("persisting") the value.  Two options I can think of: 1) Set a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), or 2) Use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("inputWidth").value = savedValue("inputHeight");
document.getElementById("inputWidth").value = savedValue("inputWidth");
        
function getValue(t){   
    var id = t.id;  
    var inputValue = t.value; 
    localStorage.setItem(id, inputValue);
}

function savedValue(t){
    if (!localStorage.getItem(t)) {
        return "";
    }
    
    return localStorage.getItem(t);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1" onkeyup="getValue(this)"> Grid Width:
<input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1" onkeyup="getValue(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use various local storage mechanisms to store this data in the browser such as Web Storage, IndexedDB, WebSQL (deprecated) and File API (deprecated and only available in Chrome) (and UserData with IE).

The simplest and most widely supported is `WebStorage` where you have persistent storage (`localStorage`) or session based (`sessionStorage`) which is in memory until you close the browser. Both share the same API.

You can for example (simplified) do something like this when the page is about to reload:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("height", $('#inputHeight').val());
    localStorage.setItem("width", $('#inputWidth').val());
    // ...
}
```

Web Storage works synchronously so this may work here. Optionally you can store the data for each blur event on the elements where the data is entered.

At page load you can check:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var height= localStorage.getItem("height");
    if (height!== null) $('#inputHeight').val("height");

    // ...
}
```

`getItem` returns `null` if the data does not exist.

Comment: thank you guys all the methods worked very well !! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use Local Storage to store the values. Local Storage has methods to retrieve and store data. Typically you'll use localStorage.getItem() on reload and localStorage.setItem() when saving datas.